# What are differences between histtype='bar' / 'stepfilled' / 'barstacked' in matplotlib.pylab.hist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Getting used to plt.hist. However, I see no differences between histtype='bar' / 'stepfilled' / 'barstacked'.
This is my code in trial

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.8, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(-2, 1, 1000)
x3 = np.random.normal(3, 2, 1000)

fig ,ax=plt.subplots(3)
kwargs = dict(alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)
ax[0].hist(x1, **kwargs)
ax[0].hist(x2, **kwargs)
ax[0].hist(x3, **kwargs)


kwargs1 = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)
ax[1].hist(x1, **kwargs1)
ax[1].hist(x2, **kwargs1)
ax[1].hist(x3, **kwargs1)

kwargs2 = dict(histtype='barstacked', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)
ax[2].hist(x1, **kwargs2)
ax[2].hist(x2, **kwargs2)
ax[2].hist(x3, **kwargs2)

plt.show()
```

and this is the result which is simply no differences[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `histtype` only applies when you pass multiple sets of data to `hist`, but you have made 9 separate calls to `hist` with one dataset each.

Compare your result to what happens when you combine the datasets:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.8, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(-2, 1, 1000)
x3 = np.random.normal(3, 2, 1000)

data = [x1, x2, x3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)

ax[0].hist(data, alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)
ax[1].hist(data, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)
ax[2].hist(data, histtype='barstacked', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=40)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: *"The reason is that histtype only applies when you pass multiple sets of data to hist"* That is incorrect. It always applies! But there is no visual difference between a bar and a filled step in case of one dataset. And `barstacked` is of course the same as `bar` if there is nothing to be stacked.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, that is what I meant.